# cannot install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

In [this tutorial](http://dev.px4.io/starting-installing-linux.html) it is recommended to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have some installation problems with the JDK and JRE software.

I have looked through forms but still cannot install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I am using "trusty".... Please advise.

Comment: readability improved to explain authors intent and issue more clearly.

Comment: fixed a spelling error I introduced